# leaflet_map not working when used in a extended template django

Tags: django, django-templates, leaflet, template-inheritance, django-leaflet

I am using django-leaflet to display on my website and It works fine and displays the map on browser when I include the leaflet_map in the base template but when I use leaflet_map on a template that extends that base template then map doesn't appear on the browser.

This is the code of extended template from base.html and it doesn't show the map on browser.

```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% load leaflet_tags %}

   {% block leaflet %}{% leaflet_js %}{% leaflet_css %}{% endblock %}



{% block content %}
  {% leaflet_map 'gis' %}
{% endblock content%}
```

These are the snippets from the base template.

```
  {% load static %}


 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>

<!-- Leaflet Info goes here -->
{% block leaflet %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>



  <div class="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in either the browser console or the server console? Your code actually works in my computer, the map is displayed. Maybe try properly closing the head tag and creating a body tag. Also, check that the view is rendering the correct template.

Comment: I found the error. As the block content was under div tags which has the css that display them as flex and and the map was direct under that tag. I solved by giving a seperate tag to map and giving it a flex 1. Thanks

Comment: @vikram Would you mind writing your solution as an answer so others can see what you did?